# Proteção de Informações ao inspecionar o código através do navegador

Tags: php, html

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de ocultar o código visível no inspecionar/ctrl+U ou dificultar. Pelo que andei pesquisando o PHP dificulta a consulta do código, confere? Quais são os métodos que vocês conhecem quanto a isso?

Comment: O código php não é possível pegar , porque ele roda no servidor, já o que está do lado do cliente(html, javascript), você pode dificultar, mas existem ferramentas automatizadas que farão o serviço de pegar esse código...Hoje em dia a maior preocupação, ao meu ver, são os dados sensíveis... Aí deve ter atenção na hora de montar sua estrutura...

Comment: +1 pelo avatar... zuera, a pergunta é boa serve para bastante usuários

Comment: No geral, não tem que se preocupar com código HTML. Deixe quem quiser copiar deixe fazer isso a vontade. A menos que seja algo muito específico que possa comprometer "parte" da segurança como um link para um video onde vc não quer que o usuario saiba qual é o link. Mas para isso existem soluções mais inteligentes (foi apenas exemplo). No final, ao tentar se proteger com técnicas do outro mundo, estará apenas  dificultando para os dois lados. Para o usuário e para você mesmo.

Comment: Relacionado [Esconder código JS](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25119/esconder-c%C3%B3digo-js)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

O PHP **não** dificulta copiar nada do front-end, você tem que entender algumas coisas primeiro:

- **front-end**

  O front-end é um termo relativo, mas na pratica ele geralmente é usado para se referir ao que será processado no navegador
- **back-end**

  O back-end também relativo, mas na pratica ele geralmente é usado para se referir as tecnologias em geral do lado do servidor, como banco de dados, programa que processa o HTTP (como Apache e IIS) e linguagem dinamica e frameworks
- **Requisição HTTP**

  É o que o navegador envia para um servidor, ocorre no momento que você digita um URL na barra de navegação, quando envia um upload
- **Resposta HTTP**

  A resposta HTTP é gerada após uma requisição HTTP e ele irá responder conforme o pedido desta requisição

O PHP é uma linguagem que pode ser usada (e geralmente é usada) para páginas web, ela roda do lado que chamamos "back-end", o navegador se comunica com o servidor através do protocolo HTTP fazendo uma requisição, então o PHP processa um script e gera uma resposta, isto tudo ocorre no servidor e não na maquina do usuário, a cada linha ou conteúdo completo gerado será enviado como "resposta HTTP" para o navegador que requisitou, por exemplo:

[image: http]

Ou seja PHP não roda junto ao HTML, ele gera uma resposta que pode ser um "documento" HTML, como pode ser um TXT, uma image, um video, vai depender do que você definiu que o PHP deve enviar de resposta.

Existem muitas outras linguagens que rodam no servidor e podem trabalhar com HTTP para gerar respostas para requisições HTTP, na pratica essas linguagens como PHP, Python (geralmente usando um framework), C# (geralmente usando asp.net e *asp.net-mvc*), Ruby (framework *Ruby on Rails*) e etc são usadas para tornar o desenvolvimento de páginas mais dinâmico, por exemplo ao acessar um perfil Facebook na verdade todos perfis são a "mesma página", mas os dados de cada perfil são "populados" conforme a requisição e o back-end gera uma versão baseada no conteúdo desejado.

### Resumindo

Em resumo não tem como proteger um HTML gerado ou criado, pois isso é um processo de download, tem como evitar algumas tentativas de cópias, mas quem realmente deseja copiar uma página vai conseguir fazer isto por mais tentativas que você faça para impedir de copiar, isso porque uma resposta HTTP é enviada como download e processada na janela do navegador, ou seja já foi baixada para máquina.

O que você tem que se preocupar é em proteger dados sensíveis, como senhas, dados de clientes (supondo que tenha um banco de dados) importantes e evitar que eles sejam exibidos em momentos indevidos.

### Técnicas para tentar proteger

Ainda sim existem coisas que você pode fazer para tentar proteger, claro que como disse os dados sensíveis não devem ser enviados como respostas, apenas se necessário, mas se os dados não são sensíveis e mesmo assim deseja protege-los.

Você pode bloquear o botão direito do mouse com javascript:

```
<script>
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
} else { //Versões antigas do IE
    document.attachEvent("oncontextmenu", function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.returnValue = false;
        return false;
    });
}
</script>
```

Você também pode bloquear a seleção de texto com CSS:

```
<style>
/*desabilita a seleção no body*/
body {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
      -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
       -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror */
         -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
          -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
              user-select: none;
}

/*habilita a seleção nos campos editaveis*/
input, textarea {
    -webkit-touch-callout: initial; /* iOS Safari */
      -webkit-user-select: text; /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
       -khtml-user-select: text; /* Konqueror */
         -moz-user-select: text; /* Firefox */
          -ms-user-select: text; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
              user-select: text;
}

/*habilita a seleção nos campos com o atributo contenteditable*/
[contenteditable=true] {
    -webkit-touch-callout: initial; /* iOS Safari */
      -webkit-user-select: all; /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
       -khtml-user-select: all; /* Konqueror */
         -moz-user-select: all; /* Firefox */
          -ms-user-select: all; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
              user-select: all;
}
</style>
```

Bloquear <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> e <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>:

> **Nota importante:** não é possível bloquear em alguns navegadores e/ou situações, isto porque existem sequencias de teclas que são reservadas, isto varia de browser para browser

```
<script>
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", bloquearSource);
} else { //Versões antigas do IE
    document.attachEvent("onkeydown", bloquearSource);
}

function bloquearSource(e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    var code = e.which || e.keyCode;

    if (
        e.ctrlKey &&
        (code == 83 || code == 85) //83 = S, 85 = U
    ) {
        if (e.preventDefault) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            e.returnValue = false;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

### Outras postagens relacionadas

- [Esconder código JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25119/3635)
- [Como compilar um arquivo PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2487/3635)
- [Dificultar o acesso aos arquivos CSS e JS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123589/3635)

Mais uma vez digo, **nenhuma "técnica" garante nada**, ele só ajuda um pouco, mas quem estiver decido a copiar a sua página vai fazer se desejar. De qualquer forma é muito mais provável que as pessoas irão preferir pegar "frameworks" como [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) e baixar layouts ou compra-los prontos ao invés de copiar o seu site.

### Sobre plágio

Ainda sim se quiser procurar outros meios de proteção talvez somente os meios legais, eu não acho que aqui no site encontrará informação útil para isto todavia de uma olhada na tag [licença](/questions/tagged/licen%c3%a7a), mas ainda sim consulte um advogado, licenciamento sobre o conteúdo é algo complexo.