# Tratamento Ajax/Json POST

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, json

Estou com Problemas no envio do Json para meu Controller em PHP:

> [image: Parametros Json]

Veja, no envio do meu Login os parâmetros que estão sendo enviados na requisição estão expostos, sendo assim uma vulnerabilidade.

A minha dúvida fica por conta se teria um método de enviar sem necessitar de uma criptografia externa, algo nativo ou um método diferente para enviar a requisição sem que os parâmetros estejam tão visíveis assim.

Editado:
Segue o código de envio da Requisição via POST

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#formlogin').submit(function(){ 
           $.ajax({         
                url:"xxxController.php",            
                type:"post",
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {
                    login: $('#email').val(),
                    senha: $('#senha').val()
                }
             })
         })   
     })
```

Comment: Pode usar HTTPS para isso.

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual a melhor maneira de criar um sistema de login com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3571/5878)

Comment: Relacionada: [Proteção de Informações ao inspecionar o código através do navegador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168911/5878)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Muito obrigado, por esclarecer minha duvida e pelas Perguntas Relacionadas.

Comment: Como o @AndersonCarlosWoss disse, o melhor é você utilizar o HTTPS, tinha dado uma suposta solução com MD5, mas daria no mesmo.